# Twitter API restrictions

Tags: python, twitter, web-scraping

We have made a little tool, in which u can put in many different twitter accounts. Lets call them Input Accounts. The tool just makes a big list of all accounts those "input accounts" are following, then ranks them for how often an account appears. So at 50 input accounts, an account can maximally appear 50 times. When running the tool, theres is a problem like this:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1699, in call
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/user1/Desktop/untitled folder 2/twitter1.py", line 67, in runThecode
    listt=returnFriends(accounts)
  File "/Users/user1/Desktop/untitled folder 2/twitter1.py", line 30, in returnFriends
    listFriends+=api.friends_ids(account)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 245, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 227, in execute
    raise RateLimitError(error_msg, resp)
tweepy.error.RateLimitError: [{'message': 'Rate limit exceeded', 'code': 88}]
```

Why is this happen and can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Twitter has a limit on how many api request you can make in a given period of time. As you are performing too many requests in a short time you exceed the rate limit. Read this blog post for more info. https://blog.twitter.com/official/en_us/a/2008/what-does-rate-limit-exceeded-mean-updated.html

you gotta do something like this. Its a pseudo code as you haven't added any sample code.

```
// whatever is twitter rate limit reset time
private const retryInSeconds = 600; 

try {
  performApiRequest();
} catch (RateLimitException e) {
   wait for retryInSeconds then performApiRequest();
}
```

Comment: is there a way to stop the tool as soon as API sais "limit reached", then continue at that point after I have new limit?